# Is there a way to pass `data` attribute of states in ui router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

Assume that we define state like this:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').config(stateConfig);

    function stateConfig($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
        .state('baseInformation', {
            parent: 'panel',
            params: {
                param1: null
            },
            data: {
                data1: 'sample data'
            },
            url: 'baseInformation',
            views: {
                'panel': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/baseInformation.html',
                    controller: 'BaseInformationController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                }
            }
        });
    }

})();
```

I want to change the value of `data` when using `$state.go`, please note i don't want to use from `params`. maybe something like this:

```
$state.go('baseInformation', {data1: 'data1 changed'});
```

Is there a way to do this, with `$state.go` or other thing?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to modify the data - this seems to be specifically what params were created for. Why don't you want to use them?

Comment: Dear Lex my main problem is that i want to change state parameter values from specific service or either controller and cannot do that. for example with something like this: `$transition$.params().param1 = -1;`

Comment: I don't know what your use case is here and this is not really the proper forum to get into that discussion, but we use `data` to set static information for a state (title, whether certain elements should be shown, etc.) because it's a nice place to consolidate all of that. `params` are meant to pass initial dynamic data to a state. I don't see that either of those require modification outside of the state transition so perhaps you are approaching whatever problem you're trying to solve from the wrong direction.

Comment: if you want to pass some dynamic custom data, then i would suggest to use $statechange to identify the state change event and pass your dynamic params. Hope this will help. $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options){ 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    // transitionTo() promise will be rejected with 
    // a 'transition prevented' error
})

Answer (score 0):

You can provide change you want as paramater in your template if needed. Read this [tutorial](http://benfoster.io/blog/ui-router-optional-parameters), it may be helpful.